# Prove that if $f$ is continuous at a point, then there is an interval around that point at which its intersection with the domain is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am working through the book *The Real Numbers and Real Analysis* by Bloch. On page 155,

> **Exercise 3.3.7.** Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a set, let $c \in A$, and let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Prove that if $f$ is continuous at $c$, then there is some $\delta > 0$ such that such that $f|A \cap (c - \delta, c + \delta)$ is bounded.

I would say to fix any $\epsilon  >  0$. By continuity of $f$ at $c$, there is $\delta  >  0$ such that for any $x \in A$ for which $|x - c| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$. Now let $x \in A \cap (c - \delta, c + \delta)$. Then we have that $x \in A$ and $c - \delta < x < c + \delta$, so that $-\delta < x - c < \delta$, and hence $|x - c| < \delta$. Then $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$, so $- \epsilon + f(c) < f(x) < \epsilon + f(c)$, for any such $x$. Since this is a fixed $\epsilon$, and $c$ is also fixed, we have that $f|A \cap (c - \delta, c + \delta)$ is bounded above and below, and hence bounded.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to choose a positive epsilon, say $\epsilon = 1$, then there is a delta $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon = 1$ if $0 < |x-c| < \delta\implies - 1 < f(x) - f(c) < 1 \implies -1 + f(c) < f(x) < 1 + f(c) \implies |f(x)| < 1 + |f(c)|= M$ which shows $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, although a little verbose. Often times it is nice to give an explicit bound $|f(x)| \leq |f(c)|+\epsilon$. I don't think it is necessary to start with $x \in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$ and then deduce that $|x-c|<\delta$, that is evident.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition

$A\subset \mathbb{R}, c\in A$

$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists \delta >0,\forall x\in A \quad |x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$

Let $\varepsilon >0$, so according to the definition, there is $\delta >0$ such as $\forall x\in (c-\delta, c+\delta)$ this inequality ($|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$) is satisfied.

then

$|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon \iff f(c)-\varepsilon<f(x)<f(c)+\varepsilon$

$\implies f$ is bounded